# Is one allowed to get a job where no minyan could be found?

Tags: halacha, employment, priorities, minyan, mincha-afternoon-prayer

If one lives in a Jewish community with access to synogogues, can one accept a job offer in a nearby city/location where there are no nearby synagogues to enable one to pray mincha with a minyan?

Let's assume that he has no issue with finding a Shachrit/Maariv minyanim when he's back at home. Also this is mostly an issue in the winter season since one can pray mincha quite late in the summer period.

Comment: I remember about 7 years ago seeing a compendium of tshuvos from the chief rabbinate discussing this issue. This issue also comes up a lot with kiruv, sometimes college campuses don't have minyanim for miles. I know someone who was in UNC for a couple years without a minyan.

Comment: I think this question is broader than just a minyan.

Comment: @bondonk, this question is about Minyan. I think the question applies, though, far beyond just a locale with no ready Minchah Minyan. It could be a subset of whether someone can move to a city with a Minyan at all.

Comment: I would say that parnoso comes first, if one cant make parnoso unless one cant daven with a minyan. That also applies to learning as well. It is no mitsva to live off others to be able to do these mitsvot.

Comment: The same question can apply to living in a place without a minyan.